# Delimit the file name while moving to another directory in Shell

Tags: shell

Im trying to move multiple files from one directory to another directory.
File name is with sequence and will be varying.
Example:

```
/global/userhome/usrsats/---------directory which has file names as below:
fl_cl_filename1
fl_cl_filename2
fl_cl_filename3
...
...
```

Now when moved to another directory, i need to get only the file name and delimit the fl_cl part.

Please help

Comment: _Which_ shell are you using? _What_ have you done so far and _what_ is your actual problem? Please edit the formatting of your question to make it more readable...

Comment: Anything beyond a simple `mv /global/userhome/usrsats/* /some/new/dir`?

Comment: (In your future questions, use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `bash`, I would do this with the **remove the matching prefix pattern** facility like this (with `DEST_DIR` set to the destination directory):

```
cd /global/userhome/usrsats
for f in *; do mv $f ${DEST_DIR}/${f#fl_cl_}; done
```